# printf not displaying 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I receive an error when trying to printf a value with 2 decimal places.

I have declared a rate and am trying to run printf as per below:

```
double rate = 2.50;
System.out.printf("Rate: %73.2d \n \n", rate);
```

However I receive this message:
    Sectors Travelled:
    3 
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
        at example.main(example.java:74)

I have also tried float similar to below:

```
float rate = 2.50;
System.out.printf("Rate: %73.2f \n \n", rate);
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem?  %d is for integer, %f is for double/float

Comment: `%73.2d` is invalid - the `d` does not mean `double` it means `integer`. (This goes back to the `C` programming language I think.)

Comment: and I don't think %73d would work.... In C, %73d puts in 72 0s before 2(bec. %d is int) since it tries to print a 73 digit integer(which is an error)

Comment: also while using floating point values, its better to use  %f instead of %d like `System.out.printf("Rate: %2f  \n", rate);` and may I know what is 73.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%73.2f` that should work. That prints your number with 2 decimal places. A `d` stand for an integer not for double.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for assisting, I changed it to .2f as suggested and also removed the double \n.  I went with: 
    System.out.printf("Rate: %73.2f \n" , rate);

Answer (score 0):

Use String Class for format and println method for print.

```
float rate=2.50f;
System.out.println(String.format("%73.2f", rate));
```

and notice one thing you wrote

```
float rate=2.50;//Compile Time Error
```

this line generate compile time error because 2.50 is double value you can not store in float,so also correct your code.

Answer (score -1):

use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat-java.lang.String-):

```
double rate = 2.50;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.printf("Rate: %s \n \n", df.format(rate));
```